# What are scanf("%*s") and scanf("%*d") format identifiers?

Tags: c, formatting, scanf

What is the practical use of the formats `"%*"` in scanf(). If this format exists, there has to be some purpose behind it. The following program gives weird output.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
        int i;
        char str[1024];

        printf("Enter text: ");
        scanf("%*s", &str);
        printf("%s\n", str);

        printf("Enter interger: ");
        scanf("%*d", &i);
        printf("%d\n", i);
        return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
manav@workstation:~$ gcc -Wall -pedantic d.c
d.c: In function ‘main’:
d.c:8: warning: too many arguments for format
d.c:12: warning: too many arguments for format
manav@manav-workstation:~$ ./a.out
Enter text: manav
D
Enter interger: 12345
372
manav@workstation:~$
```

Comment: Manav, based upon some of your recent questions, you would do well to read a text book.

Comment: @Alok: Well i have read a text book but hadn't gone into such details. Most text-books don't provide examples catering to real-time usage. I think, the best thing to do would be to read "The C Compiler Design" text-book.

Comment: @Manav: You definitely don't need a "C Compiler Design" book.  Have you tried K&R?

Comment: @Alok: I will start reading K&R but still I feel a C programming course is incomplete without adequate knowledge of Operating Systems and "C Compiler Design"

Comment: @Manav: `man 3 printf` would answer your question too.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

For printf, the * allows you to specify the minimum field width through an extra parameter, e.g. `printf("%*d", 4, 100);` specifies a field width of 4. A field width of 4 means that if a number takes less than 4 characters to print, space characters are printed until the field width is filled. If the number takes up more space than the specified field width, the number is printed as-is with no truncation.

For `scanf`, the * indicates that the field is to be read but ignored, so that e.g. `scanf("%*d %d", &i)` for the input "12 34" will ignore 12 and read 34 into the integer i.

Comment: please change this "printf("%*d", 4, 100);" to "printf("%.*d", 4, 100);"    .* should be used.

Comment: For `scanf` the fields with `*` **are not counted in the return value**.

Comment: What is a **field width**?

Comment: @JananathBanuka answer updated with an exemplification explaining the term.

Comment: Why was `printf()` add here?  It's a totally different function and not what the OP was asking for.  It's like someone asking about `strstr()` and you giving examples of `strchr()`.  As an after thought you included the request information.

Answer (score 25):

The star is a flag character, which says to ignore the text read by the specification.
To qoute from the glibc documentation:

> An optional flag character `*', which says to ignore the text read for this specification. When scanf finds a conversion specification that uses this flag, it reads input as directed by the rest of the conversion specification, but it discards this input, does not use a pointer argument, and does not increment the count of successful assignments.

It is useful in situations when the specification string contains more than one element, eg.:
 `scanf("%d %*s %d", &i, &j)` for the `"12 test 34"` - where *i* & *j* are integers and you wish to ignore the rest.

Answer (score 9):

The `*` is used to skip an input without putting it in any variable. So `scanf("%*d %d", &i);` would read two integers and put the second one in `i`.

The value that was output in your code is just the value that was in the uninitialized `i` variable - the scanf call didn't change it.

Answer (score 6):

See [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/scanf/)

> An optional starting asterisk indicates that the data is to be retrieved from stdin but ignored, i.e. it is not stored in the corresponding argument.

Answer (score 4):

In    `scanf("%*d",&a)` `*` skips the input. In order to read the inputs one has to use an extra       `"%d"` in `scanf`. For example:

```
 int a=1,b=2,c=3;
    scanf("%d %*d %d",&a,&b,&c); //input is given as: 10 20 30
```

O/p:

```
a=10 b=30 and c=3;  // 20 is skipped
```

If you use another `%d`  i.e:    `scanf("%d %*d %d %d",&a,&b,&c); //input is given as: 10 20 30 40`
then a=10 b=30 c=40.

If you use `","` in scanf then no value will be taken after `%*d` i.e;
    `scanf("%d %*d,%d" &a,&b,&c)// 10 20 30`
    O/p: 
    a=10 b=2 c=3 will be the output.