# What is the difference between %*c%c and %c as a format specifier to scanf?

Tags: c, special-characters

I typically acquire a character with `%c`, but I have seen code that used `%*c%c`. For example:

```
char a;
scanf("%*c%c", &a);
```

What is the difference?

Comment: Each of the specifiers is described in any decent book. Did you consider one before posting?

Comment: yes, I've tried to find but i found other cases. My book explay these char  %c
short, int, long  %d
short, int, long  %i
unsigned short, unsigned int, unsigned long  %u
float  %f
double  %lf
float, double (notazione scientifica)  %e
float, double [usa il più breve tra %f e %e]  %g
short, int, long (formato ottale)  %o
short, int, long (formato esadecimale)  %x
puntatore  %p
sequenza di caratteri terminata da un '\0'  %s
unsigned long long [64-bit]  %llu
long long [64-bit]  %ll
long double [64-bit]  %Lf
unsigned short [8-bit]  %hu Can you explain me the difference? please

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are scanf("%\*s") and scanf("%\*d") format identifiers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155518/what-are-scanfs-and-scanfd-format-identifiers)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In a `scanf` format string, after the `%`, the `*` character is the *assignment-suppressing character*.

In your example, it eats the first character but does not store it.

For example, with:

```
char a;
scanf("%c", &a);
```

If you enter: `xyz\n`, (`\n` is the new line character) then `x` will be stored in object `a`.

With:

```
scanf("%*c%c", &a);
```

If you enter: `xyz\n`, `y` will be stored in object `a`.

C says specifies the `*` for `scanf` this way:

> (C99, 7.19.6.2p10) Unless assignment suppression was indicated by a *, the result of the conversion is placed in the object pointed to by the first argument following the format argument that has not already received a conversion result.

Answer (score 5):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scanf_format_string):

> An optional asterisk (*) right after the percent symbol denotes that
>   the datum read by this format specifier is not to be stored in a
>   variable. No argument behind the format string should be included for
>   this dropped variable.

It is so you can skip the character matched by that asterisk.

Answer (score 1):

Basically ***%c*** refers to the character type specifier and ***%*c*** is used to exclude one character such that the character would be read from the console but it wouldn't be assigned to any variable.
for eg. -:

suppose the input is  *31/12/2018*  and you want to output in the form of integers only and want to exclude '/' characters then you can use %*c here as -
                scanf("%d%*c%d%*c%d" , &day,&month,&year);

so this way you will exclude two '/' characters.

In similar manner **%*d** is used to exclude one integer, 
**%*f** to exclude one float , and **%*s** to exclude one word of the string.
Hope it helped :)