# What does an asterisk in a scanf format specifier mean?

Tags: c, char, scanf, format-specifiers

So I stumbled across this code and I haven't been able to figure out what the purpose of it is, or how it works:

```
int word_count;
scanf("%d%*c", &word_count);
```

My first thought was that `%*d` was referencing a `char` pointer or disallowing `word_count` from taking `char` variables.

Can someone please shed some light on this?

Comment: See: [The difference between %*c%c and %c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11109750/the-difference-between-cc-and-c)

Comment: [**fscanf documentation**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf).

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`*c` means, that a char will be read but won't be assigned, for example for the input "30a" it will assign 30 to `word_count`, but 'a' will be ignored.

Answer (score 24):

The `*` in `"%*c"` stands for `assignment-suppressing character *`: *If this option is present, the function does not assign the result of the conversion to any receiving argument.*<sup>1</sup> So the character will be read but not assigned to any variable.

---

<sub>**Footnotes:**</sub>

<sub>1. [fscanf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf)</sub>

Answer (score 15):

To quote the `C11` standard, chapter §7.21.6.2, *fscanf()*

> [...] Each conversion specification is introduced by the character `%`.
>   After the %, the following appear in sequence:
>
> — An optional assignment-suppressing character `*`.
>   — [...]
>   — A *conversion specifier* character

and regarding the behavior,

> [..] Unless assignment suppression was indicated by a `*`, the
>   result of the conversion is placed in the object pointed to by the first argument following
>   the format argument that has not already received a conversion result. [...]

That means, in case of a format specifier like `"%*c"`, a `char` will be read from the `stdin` but the scanned value won't get stored or assigned to anything. So, you don't need to supply a corresponding parameter.

So, in this case,

```
scanf("%d%*c", &word_count);
```

is a **perfectly valid** statement.

For example, What it does in a *nix environment is to clear the input buffer from the `newline` which is stored due to pressing <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key after the input.