# warning: format ‘%f’ expects type ‘float *’, but argument 4 has type ‘int *’

Tags: c

I'm getting this error:

> warning: format ‘%f’ expects type ‘float *’, but argument 4 has type
>   ‘int *’

on this line:

```
temp = sscanf(data,"%*c %d %f %f %f",&uptime, &inputs,  &systemstatus.adc4, &voltage, &idle);
```

and i don't understand why that is, can somebody explain this to me?

Im using a GCC compiler with make,

```
#include "main.h"

void processcmd(char *data) {
    char foo[300];
    int temp, temp2, temp3;
    _statusstruct tempstatus;
    int uptime;
    int inputs;
    float voltage;
    float idle;

    if (data[0] != 'S') { sprintf(foo,"> %s",data); menu_main_log(foo); }

    switch (data[0]) {
        case 'S':           
            temp = sscanf(data,"%*c %d %d %f %f %f %f %f %d %d",
                &tempstatus.uptime,&tempstatus.inputs, &tempstatus.adc0, &tempstatus.adc1,
                &tempstatus.adc2,  &tempstatus.adc3, &tempstatus.voltage, &tempstatus.idle,
                &tempstatus.debug);
            if (tempstatus.uptime < systemstatus.uptime) {
                // big trouble: IO card rebooted.
                state = STATE_RESET;
                systemstatus.uptime = 0;
                printf("Detected IO reboot\n");
                break;
            } else if (temp == 9) {     
                memcpy(&systemstatus,&tempstatus,((char*)&tempstatus.newdata) - ((char*)&tempstatus));
                for (temp = 0; temp < 16; temp++) {
                    if (systemstatus.inputs & (1<<temp)) buttons[temp][2] = 1;
                    else buttons[temp][2] = 0;
                }
                systemstatus.newdata = 1;
            } else {
                printf("Status line was invalid (%d)\n", temp);
            }
            break;
        case 'I':           
            temp = sscanf(data,"%*c %d %d", &temp2, &temp3);
            if (temp == 2) {
                if (temp2 >= 0 && temp2 <= 15 && (temp3 == 0 || temp3 == 1)) {
                    buttons[temp2][temp3] = 1; 
                }
                buttons[temp2][2] = temp3;      // current state
                if (temp2 >= 3 && temp2 <= 6  && temp3 == 1) buzzer_on(5000,200);
            }
            break;
        case 'E':           // error report. rest of the line is the text

            break;
        case 'O':           // reply on output status set/request

            break;
        case 'T':           // reply on heater setting set/request

            break;
        case 'C':           // reply on calibration command

            break;
        case 'H':           // reply on calibration command

            temp = sscanf(data,"%*c %d %f %f %f",&uptime, &inputs,  &systemstatus.adc4, &voltage, &idle);

            break;

        default:
            printf("Unknown command: %s\n",data);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is type of `voltage`?

Comment: The message should be pretty self-explanatory. It tells you what the compiler expected and what you actually passed.

Comment: it seems that you have declared `int inputs;` instead of `float inputs;`

Comment: Is it just me, or is argument *4* `inputs`, not `voltage`?

Comment: @Biffen you are right.

Comment: look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155518/what-is-scanfs-and-scanfd-format-identifiers) - this could help you - corresponding to this post `&inputs` corresponds to the first `%f`

Comment: @Biffen: The error message just refers to the format string (counting the argument references - apparently starting with `1`) and the arguments following it (i.e. the variadic arguments).

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: @Olaf When I tried it (at http://cpp.sh) it (GCC) counted *all* the arguments, so #4 = `inputs`.

Comment: @Biffen: Occam's Razor: OP does not state which compiler it is and the format-specifier for `inputs` is `%d`. So the logical conclusion would be it counts the "format-string arguments", not the function arguments.

Comment: @Olaf The error message looks *exactly* like GCC's, but sure, it could be some other compiler. Do you know one that only counts the ‘format-string arguments’? And no, `%d` is for `uptime`, `%f` is for `input` (`%*c` has *no* variable).

Comment: @Biffen: Ahh, sorry, I missinterpreted the `*` (I seldom can use `printf` in my projects). On second thought, that looks even more unclear. I voted to close, because OP is missing further information. Any answer would be pure speculation.

Comment: @mmkevind **Post update** Check the format specifiers and their corresponding variables' types. `%d` for `int`, `%f` for float, etc. And remember that `%*c` doesn't count. Currently there's at least one mismatch, as well as the wrong number in total.

Comment: Either change `sscanf(data,"%*c %d %f %f %f",&uptime, &inputs,  &systemstatus.adc4, &voltage, &idle);` to `sscanf(data,"%*c %d %d %f %f",&uptime, &inputs,  &systemstatus.adc4, &voltage, &idle);` or change `int inputs;` to `float inputs;`. Also there seems to be one extra argument. Remove the unnecessary one.

Comment: i will try that thanks, ps do you think this can cause a Segmentation fault on the software?

Comment: @cool-guy the change  to sscanf(data,"%*c %d %d %f %f",.... worked

Comment: regarding these lines: 'printf("Detected IO reboot\n");
                break;'  this break statement should be removed  it breaks the switch statement syntax and is completely unneeded

Answer (score 3):

If you read e.g. [this `scanf` (and family) reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf), you will see that the asterisk in a format is for *suppressing* writing to anything.

So you have a format that will skip one character, then read an integer and three floating-point values. However, you pass *five* arguments to the function, the last one which will be ignored.

I assume that you only meant to pass four arguments, to match the format.

---

Just speculating, but if you have the first format (`"%*c"`) to skip a newline (or any other white-space), the linked reference should also tell you that it's not needed, the `"%d"` format-specifier will skip all leading white-space (which includes space, tab and newline).