# Format string with multiple percent signs

Tags: c, printf, string-formatting, c-strings

I know `%%` is used to escape actual `%` signs in a string, so `%%%ds` will end up with `%10s` in the following format string, but I don't know why I need `%%5s` in this string?

After all, there are only two additional arguments (BUFFSIZE / 10).

```
#define BUFFSIZE 100
char buf[100]={0}
sprintf(buf, "%%5s %%%ds %%%ds", BUFFSIZE / 10, BUFFSIZE / 10);
```

After running the code above, the buf will contain the string,

```
%10s %10s
```

Comment: I get `%5s %10s %10s` in `buf`, demo here http://ideone.com/c8MhN6. What did _you_ expect?

Comment: This means someone is either overly clever or doesn't know about [`%*s`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7105890/set-variable-text-column-width-in-printf).

Comment: @n.m. or, is not afraid of the maintainer (_Ref: the violent psychopath_)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The purpose is to get a format string to use it in another function that needs a format string like `sscanf()`.

With your code you get: `%5s %10s %10s` written to your `buf`, [see online](https://ideone.com/bqKvWm), which means it will accept three strings with a length identifier.

```
%%5s          --> %5s
%%%ds with 10 --> %10s (read it that way: {%%}{%d}{s})
```

That buffer `%5s %10s %10s` could now be used in a `sscanf()` call like shown [here](https://ideone.com/sWF6y7).

But there is a best practice to prevent a buffer overflow caused by `sscanf()` which is also described by Kernighan and Pike in their book [The Practice of Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/020161586X), see [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1621973/8051589).

---

The reason why you maybe can't use `%*s` may be, see [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2155564/8051589):

> For `printf`, the * allows you to specify minimum field width through an extra parameter, i.e. `printf("%*d", 4, 100);` specifies a field width of 4.
>
> For `scanf`, the * indicates that the field is to be read but ignored, so that i.e. `scanf("%*d %d", &i)` for the input "12 34" will ignore 12 and read 34 into the integer i.

Answer (score 2):

`%` in itself is a valid conversion specifier. The prescribed syntax is, as mentioned in `C11`, chapter §7.21.6.1/P2, (*emphasis mine*)

> Each conversion specification is introduced by the character `%`. **After the `%`, the following
>   appear in sequence:**
>
> - Zero or more flags [...]
> - An optional minimum field width.
> - An optional precision [...]
> - An optional length modifier [...]
> - **A conversion specifier character that specifies the type of conversion to be applied.**

Then, from P8, for conversion specifiers

> The conversion specifiers and their meanings are:
>
> ......
>
> `%`
>
> **A `%` character is written. No argument is converted. The complete
>   conversion specification shall be `%%`.**

So, based on greedy approach, compiler will group a syntax like

```
 ....   %%%ds, BUFFSIZE / 10 ....
```

as

```
 {%%}{%d}{s}
  ^^--------------------------Replaced as %
      ^^----------------------Actual conversion specification happens, argument is used
         ^^------------------just part of final output
```

which finally produces

```
  %Xs    //where X is the value of (BUFFSIZE / 10)
```

which is a valid format string (*`%`, minimum field width, conversion specifier, all in order*), again, to be used later.

Comment: you explained everything, my mistake

Comment: @VishwajeetVishu Nevermind, It's OK. I was also updating the answer in the meantime. :)

Answer (score 0):

The OP is computing a format string from parametric sizes.  Given the arguments, the string will contain `%5s %10s %10s`, which can be used with either `printf` or `scanf`:

```
printf("%5s %10s %10s", "A", "B", "C");
```

outputs:

```
    A          B          C

char a[6], b[11], c[11];
scanf("%5s %10s %10s", a, b, c);
```

will read 3 strings into `a`, `b`, `c` but limits the number of characters read for each string to prevent buffer overflow.

Note however that for the `printf` case, it is not necessary to compute the string as posted, since you could have used:

```
printf("%5s %*s %*s", "A", BUFFSIZE / 10, "B", BUFFSIZE / 10, "C");
```

Unfortunately, `scanf()` attaches different semantics to the `*` format modifier and it is not possible to specify the maximum number of characters to store with an argument, only with digits in the format string, hence need for a separate formatting step.