# sprintf formatting - Three '%%%' before u and two '%%' before n?

Tags: c, printf, scanf, string-formatting

In a group assignment, we have to read input which only consist of the (small) letters *a-z* and the characters have a max length of 255. I wanted to check with getchar and ASCII, but my partner found a solution using sprintf and scanf, which I do not totally understand:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

int result = 0;

unsigned int length = 255;
char input[257];

result = readInput(input, &length);

return 1;
}

int readInput(char *output, int *length) {

char format_pattern[15]; 
sprintf(format_pattern, "%%%u[^\n]%%n", *length); 

printf("Max allowed length is %d\n",*length);

scanf(format_pattern, output, length);

printf("Input length is %d\n",*length);

return 1;

}
```

Output: 
`Max allowed length is 255
testinput
Input length is 9`

How does the format pattern in sprintf and scanf work?
Especially the three `%%%` before `u` and the two `%%` before `n` - I tried changing this to `%u[^\n]%n` because two `##` would escape the ´%´, but then I get an error so they have to be there.

The only things I figured out are:

- the `%n` can read the characters before it, e.g.:

  ```
  int var;

  printf("Some Text before%n and after",&var); 
  printf("characters before percent n = %d\n", var);
  ```

  Output: `Some Text before and aftercharacters before percent n = 16`

  but in my big example above there isn't a pointer variable, where the
  amount of text could be stored since `*length` is for `%%%u`?
- The [^\n] means something like "read till new Line"

I googled a lot but did not find a similiar example - could somebody help me?

Comment: " the characters have a max length of 255" - what does that mean? `char` has a fixed size of `CHAR_BIT` bits (and that's typically much less than 255). Also which language is this, C or C++? Why is it tagged with two different languages? If your partner came up with this code, he should be able to explain. (unless your partner's name is "google")

Comment: To understand the format string, you could simply check what is the result in `format_pattern`. You could simply print it or watch it in a debugger. In most cases seeing the result helps to understand what is going on.

Comment: "but my partner found a solution using sprintf and scanf, which I do not totally understand:" --> Why not ask your partner?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to escape the % (percent) sign in C's printf?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1860159/608639), [Format string with multiple percent signs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44777298/608639), [What are scanf(“%*s”) and scanf(“%*d”) format identifiers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2155518/608639), etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your partner is using `sprintf()` to dynamically create a format string for `scanf()`.  This is a bit tricky, because the `printf` and `scanf` functions use mostly the same formatting language.  The reason for the dynamic format creation appears to be to insert a configurable field width into the format. That's clever, but overcomplicated and wholly unnecessary.

> How does the format pattern in sprintf and scanf work? Especially the three %%% before u and the two %% before n

`%%%u` is actually *two* directives.  The first `%%` causes `printf` to emit a single `%` character, and that leaves `%u`, which I think you recognize.  Similarly, the `%%n` is *one* directive (`%%`, as described above) plus a literal 'n' character, which is emitted as-is.  The overall `sprintf` call prepares a format string something like `"%255[^\n]%n"`.

How, then, does the resulting format work with `scanf`?  You should probably read its documentation, available all over, such as [here](https://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf).  That one happens to be for the GLIBC implementation, but you're not using anything non-standard, so it should explain everything you need to know about your particular format.  Specifically, the 255 that you go to such trouble to introduce is a maximum field width for a field consisting of characters in the "scanset" described by `[^\n]` -- every character except newline.  The `%n` does not consume any input; instead, it stores the number of characters so far read by that `scanf` call.

For your purposes, I see absolutely no reason to generate the `scanf` format dynamically.  You are *given* a maximum field width, so you might as well use it in a literal format string.  Even if you wanted a maximum field width specified at runtime, `scanf()` has a better mechanism than dynamically writing format strings, involving passing the wanted field width as an argument.

*Bonus hint*: the code you posted is terribly mixed up about where to use `*length` and where just `length` in your `printf` and `scanf` calls.  Where you want to *output* its value, you must pass the value (`length`).  Where you want `scanf` to *modify* the value, you must pass the address where the new value should be stored (`*length`).

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `x` is a (large enough) char array

```
sprintf(x, "%%"); // put a single % (and '\0') in x
sprintf(x, "%u", 8); // put 8 (and '\0') in x

sprintf(x, "%%%u", 8); // put %8 (and '\0') in x
```

Comment: so my code `sprintf(format_pattern, "%%%u[^\n]%%n", *length);` means:

"put %256 (*length), [^\n] and %n in format_pattern"

Right?

Comment: Right, except `*length` is 255 :)